# Is it possible to process the push notification data in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

i have a question for my student project.

I am currently using push notification an the Windows Phone 7 and wanted to ask if it is possible - like as it is in Android - to process the delivered data in background, creating a wakelock or something.

Here the scenerio how it works in Android:
1. I send a notification to the device (more precise to the C2DM Server, but that doesn't matters now).
2. The App receives my notification while it is closed, shows a tile on the screens and saves the data in a database so i can work with them later.

Is it possible to store the data received by a push notification in a database/isolated storage in Windows Phone 7 while the Application is not running?

Answer (score 0):

This capability isn't exposed directly by the API at the moment. However, there is nothing stopping you calling back to your web service after the user taps your toast notification to query for any data that needs to be passed along.

Comment: Thank you, than i have another question...is there a possibility to check if the application was started due to a click on a tile?

Comment: There isn't at the moment. Hopefully in your scenario you're able to utilise data from the web service that will satisfy both toast loads and non toast loads. One suggestion I've offered before if you're trying to do something specific from a toast tap, is to offer some context of recent toast(s) when you land in the app (regardless of tap toast or from start menu).

Answer (score 0):

As Mick said. That's not possible at the moment.

Tile and toast notifications are intended to be used provide updated information to the user or prompt the user that there is more information availabel.

If this then prompts the user to open the app, that should be the trigger for the app to get any new information from the server. You can then save/store this information as appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It's possible 
You can check out this link [How to: Send a Push Notification for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402545%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: the question is specifically about responding to received notifications when the app is NOT running. That is not possible at the moment. The article you have linked to handles processing notifications when the app is running or is launched in response to a received toast notification.