# Microsoft Push Notification Service And Windows Phone 7/8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, push-notification, windows-phone-8, mpns

I have few questions regarding MPNS(Microsoft Push Notification Service) For Windows Phone.

As we know there are three types of Push Notifications in windows phone

1. Toast Notification
2. Shell Tile Notification
3. Raw Data Notification
4. Can we show Toast and Tile at the same time. Mean when toast is received via MPNS and it also updates my tile count too for my app tile.
5. Suppose my app is not launched and its not in running state or its in background. If there is some toast or tile notification is received. And server send some payload in this push. Can we get that when app launched after the push and we can get this payload within our app.
6. What is TTL(Time To Live) time of push or can we set that within our payload.

Comment: Wp8 brought new kind of notifications - voip ;-)

Comment: @Nagg: Its Just For Incoming Call Task And We Need New Capability For That As Per My Knowledge. But In My Way I Am Not Going For VOIP. I Just want to use for IM or Marketing Push. Thats Was My Question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For raw and VoIP toasts, a background agent can handle the incoming push, and you can then write data to the isolated storage. A raw/VoIP toast can also update a tile, and show a message toast at the same time, for a single push payload.

Tile and Message Toasts have by definition no agent, so no code handling the incoming data.

> What is TTL(Time To Live) time of push or can we set that within our payload.

You got **30 seconds** before the OS kills the agent process.

Comment: Hi Claus, How can the application process the raw push if its not in foreground? Does the os do it for us? How to invoke the background agent if its not running in such a case?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this answer seems to be incorrect. According to this topic on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962%28v=vs.105%29.aspx. It says that you can NOT utilize anything from the Microsoft.Phone.Notification namespace in a background agent. This really sucks, as that was exactly what I wanted to do and this answer made me think it was possible. Claus, I see that you work for Skype. Is this perhaps something you can only do through a private API?

Comment: I never wrote you could do it using those APIs. If you wish to create a VoIP app with RAW chat push, you should contact Microsoft.

Comment: "For raw and VoIP toasts, a background agent can handle the incoming push ..." sure sounds like you can use a background agent to handle a raw push notification. I wish that were true. The situation is I want to update a custom live tile when I get a push. Unfortunately, it appears that's not possible. I can use a Tile notification, but then I'm limited to the default tile template. So the situation is, you can have a custom tile OR update it through push, but not both. That sucks.

Comment: You can do that, if you use a push template that works for both toasts and tiles. RAW push is explicitly for providers that implement their own protocol, such as Skype.

Comment: But sure, downvote the correct answer to the actual question, because it doesn't answer your own question which should be in another post altogether.

Comment: I'll be happy to vote it back up if you can be more clear. I still don't see how your answer is correct. My app cannot handle a raw push in a background agent, but your answer says it can. The only clarification is in your comment that only if it's a VoIP app and only with permission from MS. That makes the actual answer misleading to me. The original question does not indicate that he wants to build a VoIP app (and his comment explicitly indicates it's not for a VoIP app).

Comment: RAW is only supported for VoIP :) And as already mentioned, you should contact Microsoft if you wish to have RAW support in your application.

Comment: I tried to vote the answer back up, but I can't unless the answer is edited. I think that should happen anyway, because I still don't think it's clear in the answer itself. Too much info is buried in these comments now. :-)  Also, I still don't think I can do what I want, despite your comment that I can. I have a custom drawn live tile, updated in a background agent. I know of no way to trigger the drawing of that tile through a push notification, which is what I want to do.

Comment: I fail to see how a raw notification could possibly update a tile when the app is NOT running, unless the notification wakes up the app (does it?) and the app manually updates the tile accordingly.

Comment: @Andrew a raw notification will run a registered background agent that can update the tile.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we show Toast and Tile at the same time. Mean when toast is received via MPNS and it also updates my tile count too for my app tile.

You have to do two different pushes for this. It's different payloads.

> Suppose my app is not launched and its not in running state or its in
>   background. If there is some toast or tile notification is received.
>   And server send some payload in this push. Can we get that when app
>   launched after the push and we can get this payload within our app.

You mean save some data into for example isolated storage when the notification is received? That is not possible.
[Is it possible to process the push notification data in Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311662/is-it-possible-to-process-the-push-notification-data-in-windows-phone-7)